# AsyncStorage React-native - {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

Беру пример кода с официальной страницы @react-native-async-storage/async-storage и вставляю свои данные для теста:

```
const setStringValue = async (value: string) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', value)
  } catch(e) {
    // save error
  }

  console.log('Done.')
}

const getMyStringValue = async () => {
  try {
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
  } catch(e) {
    // read error
  }

  console.log('Done.')

}

setStringValue('qwerty');
console.log(getMyStringValue());
```

В консоли получаю это:

```
{"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}
```

В чем причина?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вывести в логе результат асинхронной функции.
Чтобы это сработало, вам необходимо сначала дождаться результата выполнения этой функции.
Например так:

```
const fn = async () => {
  const result = await getMyStringValue();
  console.log(result);
}
fn();
```